# recursive definition of path length of a tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree

A convinent way to compute the path length of a tree is to sum, for all k, the product of k and the umber of nodes at level k.

The path length of a tree is the sum of the levels of all the tree's nodes. The path length can have simple recursive definition as follows.

The path length of a tree with N nodes is the sum of the path lengths of the subtrees of its root plus N-1.

I am not able to follow above recursive defintion. Kindly explain with simple example.

Comment: What is the path length of an empty tree or a trivial two-node tree? Only then is the recursive definition complete. I don't quite understand what this path length is or what is it for but it may help if you consider that a tree with N vertices has N-1 edges.

Comment: @bixiclop: I added some info above. Hope it helps in answering

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Understanding the recursion

> The path length can have simple recursive definition as follows.
>
> The path length of a tree with N nodes is the sum of the path lengths of the subtrees of its root plus N-1.

First, you have to understand what the path length is: It is the sum of all the distances between the nodes and the root.

With this thought in mind, it is trivial to see that the path length for a root node without children is 0: There are no nodes with a distance to the root node.

Let's assume we already know the path length of some trees. If we were to create a new node `R`, to which we connect all trees we already have, think about how the distances to the root node change.

Previously, the distances were measured to the root of the trees (now subtrees). Now, there's one more step to be made to the root node, i.e. all distances increase by one.

Thus, we add `N - 1`, because there are `N - 1` descendants from the root node, which are now all one further from the root , and `1*(N-1) = N-1`

---

You calculate the path length easily in several ways, you can either count the edges or the nodes.

### Counting Nodes

```
             A        Level 0
           /   \      
          B     C     Level 1
         / \   / \
        D   E F   G   Level 2
```

We start with a path length of 0:

- Node `A` is the root, which is always on level 0. It does not contribute to the path length. (You don't need to follow any paths to reach it, hence 0)

  - `0 + (0) = 0`
- On level 1, you have two nodes: `B` and `C`:

  - `0 + (1 + 1) = 2`
- On level 2, you have four nodes: `D, E, F` and `G`:

  - `2   + (2 + 2 + 2 + 2) = 10`

### Counting edges

```
             A        
           /   \      Level 1
          B     C     
         / \   / \    Level 2
        D   E F   G
```

- `0`, our initial sum
- `+ 1*2` On level `1`, there are `2` edges
- `+ 2*4` On level `2`, there are `4` edges

### Translating the definition into maths

> A convinent way to compute the path length of a tree is to sum, for all k, the product of k and the umber of nodes at level k.

Let L<sub>i</sub> denote the set of nodes on level `i` and `h` denote the height, i.e. maximum distance from a node to the root:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
             A
           /   \
          B     C
         / \   / \
        D   E F   G
```

Here, N = total no. of nodes in tree = 7

(The path length of a leaf node is taken as zero.)

Acc. to recursive definition:

```
Path length of tree = Path length with Root A
                    = Path length with Root B + Path length with Root C + (7-1)

                    = (Path length with Root D + Path length with Root E + (3-1))
                    + (Path length with Root F + Path length with Root G + (3-1))
                    + (7-1)

                    = ((0 + 0 + 2) + (0 + 0 + 2)) + 6
                    = 10
```

Its implementation could be as follows:

```
int Recurse(Node root, int totalNodes)
{
    if (totalNodes == 1)
        return 0;
    int noOfNodes1 = CountNodes(root.left);
    int noOfNodes2 = CountNodes(root.right);
    return ( Recurse(root.left, noOfNodes1)
           + Recurse(root.right, noOfNodes2) + totalNodes - 1);
}
```

Comment: Your interpretation is wrong. In your example, there are subtrees B and C. Both of these have a path length of 2: 3 nodes - 1. Now, for the entire subtree, it's 7 - 1 + both subtrees = 10.

Comment: No, it's 10. The mistake you made is that the path length of a tree with only a single node is `0`, not `1`.

Comment: Do you mean that a leaf node is at level zero? if yes, then it could be 10.

Comment: It's still incorrect: There should not be any ones. A tree with only a single node has path length 0. Going from that to your subtree B is: 0 + (3-1)=2.

Comment: Yes, the path length of `subtree starting at <leaf node>` is `(1-1) = 0`.

Comment: Also note that implementation is horribly inefficient, since you are calculating the size of subtrees many times unnecessarily. The solution is to either modify the tree nodes to track how many nodes are in the subtree rooted at that node, or to calculate the subtree size and subtree path length at the same time.

Comment: @verdesmarald: I agree. I just tried to have something closer to pragramming to make OP understand.

Comment: @Azodious that was when the edit you made still read `14` ;) I have removed my downvote because you corrected it.